# Unexpected output. Please explain

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been trying to figure out the reasons behind the output of the following Java program:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Implementation");
      }
    };
    MyThread gaurav = new MyThread(r);
    new Thread(r).start();
    gaurav.start();
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

  Runnable runnable;
  public MyThread(Runnable r) {
    runnable = r;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    super.run();
    System.out.println("Thread");
  }
}
```

Output for above is : 'Implementation' followed by 'Thread' in next line. Now the problem lies in this statement :

```
gaurav.start();
```

As I have passed the runnable r to MyThread, I thought that r would get executed, hence, the output would be 'Implementation' for this too. But clearly, I am missing something. Also a difference between the statements:

```
new Thread(r).start();
        gaurav.start();
```

for this scenario would be really useful. Thanks.

Comment: You're only putting `runnable` into a field in `MyThread`, nowhere do you run it. That's why it's not outputting anything as part of `MyThread`. You could as well not pass a `Runnable` to `MyThread` as far as output is concerned.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But still not getting the reason why I got down votes even when I had tried this question a lot before posting here.

Comment: @gauravjain stackoverflow community got lot of these "don't waste time reading question bodies, read title only" and they assumed you are confused about the order of execution and it has been asked before. They are racing for getting an answer accepted.

Comment: @mostruash Yeah I guess I'd be more careful with the title now onwards. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Implementation");
      }
    };
    MyThread gaurav = new MyThread(r);
    gaurav.start();
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

  Runnable runnable;
  public MyThread(Runnable r) {
    // calling Thread(Runnable r) constructor.
    super(r);
    // runnable isn't used anywhere. You can omit the following line.
    runnable = r;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // First it will run whatever Runnable is given
    // into Thread's constructor.
    super.run();
    System.out.println("Thread");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Implementation
Thread
```

I guess your confusion comes from your `Runnable` field in `MyThread`. You think that by having it there, you somehow override `Thread`'s own runnable but you don't. If you want to do that, you should call `super(r)` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

MyThread's start method will start the thread's run method in which you have `System.out.println("Thread");`

While `new Thread(r).start();` will run the `System.out.println("Implementation");`

It's solely on OS's scheduler which thread would run first. So you might see the output as:

```
Implementation
Thread
```

Or

```
Thread
Implementation
```

Comment: He's simply asking why both threads won't output `Implementation`. I don't think he's asking about the order of execution.